# Select IDs which satisfy a condition in each repetition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select from column ID those unique elements which are completed. Each ID represent a task and can appear multiple times. A task is completed only when the status column has a value of 100 for every row.
Example of dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'ID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Status': [100, 100, 100, 25, 100, 34]})
```

Expected result:

```
  ID  Status
0  A     100
4  C     100
```

- A: appears twice with 100. A is completed
- B: appears twice but one with 25. B is incompleted
- C: appears once with 100. C is completed
- D: appears once with 34. D is incompleted.

This is my work so far:

```
df_completed = df[df['Status']==100].drop_duplicates()

df_filtered = df[df.ID.isin(df_completed.ID) & (df.Status<100)]

df_completed = df_completed[~df_completed.ID.isin(df_filtered.ID)]
```

As you can see, I am able to produce the correct result but I wonder if there is a less convoluted way to do it. Moreover, the code is to be shared and df is huge, so simplicity and efficiency are most welcome.

Comment: `ID` seems like a confusing name for a field which is not unique...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good use case for `groupby`.
Here are a couple of examples:

`df.groupby("ID").apply(lambda df: (df.Status == 100).all())`

This gives a boolean status for each ID:

```
ID
A     True
B    False
C     True
D    False
```

Another option if the mean can be relied upon:

`df.groupby("ID").mean().pipe(lambda df: df[df.Status == 100])`

This gives the result:

```
ID  Status
A   100.0
C   100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the variable is a status I'm assuming it exists exclusively [0,100]? If so the minimum status must be 100 for that ID.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'ID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Status': [100, 100, 100, 25, 100, 34]})
df_completed=df.groupby(['ID']).min()==100 #gives True/False for each ID.
df_completed=df_completed[df == True].dropna()*100 #essentially just formatting
```

Output:

```
    Status
ID
A    100.0
C    100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do it.

**Option 1**

`groupby()` and filter out `min==100`

```
df.groupby('ID')['Status'].min()[lambda x:x==100].reset_index()

ID  Status
0  A     100
1  C     100
```

**Option 2**
Filter `IDs` that have any `Status` not equal to `100` and extract their `index` using `groupby()`, `filter(boolean selection)`

Exclude selected index using reversed `.isin` query and `drop duplicates` from the outcome

```
s=df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['Status'].filter(lambda x:(x!=100).any()).index,:]
df[~df.index.isin(s.index)].drop_duplicates()


   ID  Status
0  A     100
4  C     100
```